# MySQL server config file permissions on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, permissions, mysql

Today, I realized that on Ubuntu 18.04, the usual MySQL (version 5.7.26) config file in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` is a symbolic link and and world-readable/writable. What is interesting is that the file that it points to is another symbolic link pointing back to `my.cnf`. Why is that? And if we want to change the config, which file should we edit? Also, isn't it a really awful decision to make it world-readable/writable by default?

```
# ls -l /etc/mysql/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 21 16:30 conf.d
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  120 Apr 25 18:10 debian-start
-rw------- 1 root root  317 May 21 16:30 debian.cnf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   24 May 21 16:30 my.cnf -> /etc/alternatives/my.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  839 Aug  3  2016 my.cnf.fallback
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  682 Jan 12  2018 mysql.cnf
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 21 16:30 mysql.conf.d

# ls -l /etc/alternatives/my.cnf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 May 21 16:30 /etc/alternatives/my.cnf -> /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf
```

Note: This is a clean Ubuntu & MySql installation with `mysql_secure_installation` command. Nothing else has been changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symlinks are always world readable/writeable. The permissions of the target file is the only thing that matters. Changing permissions on a symlink changes permissions on target file:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 vidarlo users 0 May 21 19:10 a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 vidarlo users 1 May 21 19:10 b -> a
$ chmod 755 b
$ ls -la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vidarlo users 0 May 21 19:10 a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 vidarlo users 1 May 21 19:10 b -> a
```

The target, `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf` is not world writable. Thus a user will not be able to overwrite it, independent of the symlinks.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that It's possible to change the file pointed by a link and create another config file (in /tmp for example) to overwrite the config ?