# Is it possible to change the permissions for the symbolic link?

Tags: command-line, permissions, directory, symbolic-link

I am trying to change the permissions for the symbolic link.

[image: Making directory and symbolic link]

As how you can see in the image, the soft link has 777 permissions, but i would like to change that.

I tried to change that by:

1. `chmod 755 someLink` - but this changes linked directory (someDir) permission.
2. `chmod -h 755 someLink` - this brings eroor `chmod: invalid option --'h'`

Is there a way how to change symbolic link permissions? I am on Ubuntu 18.04

Many thanks in advance

Comment: -h is freebsd/openbsd so MacOS. Not Linux ;-) https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=chmod&manpath=SuSE+Linux/i386+11.3 Linux "chmod never changes the permissions of symbolic links; the chmod system call cannot change their permissions. This is not a problem since the permissions of symbolic links are never used. However, for each symbolic link listed on the command line, chmod changes the permissions of the pointed-to file. In contrast, chmod ignores symbolic links encountered during recursive directory traversals."  https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod

Comment: Thanks. Now i got it. How i understand on MacOS you can change the symbolic link permissions, is that right?

Comment: yes more generic: on freebsd/openbsd you can (mac os uses openbsd). Those are UNIX clones so not Linux and UNIX has a couple of features in commands we never got in Linux).

Comment: Related (on [unix.se]): [Why do Linux/POSIX have lchown but no lchmod?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224979/why-do-linux-posix-have-lchown-but-no-lchmod)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

While not an exact duplicate, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145107/mysql-server-config-file-permissions-on-ubuntu-18-04/1145114#1145114) should provide a hint:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 vidarlo users 0 May 21 19:10 a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 vidarlo users 1 May 21 19:10 b -> a
$ chmod 755 b
$ ls -la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vidarlo users 0 May 21 19:10 a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 vidarlo users 1 May 21 19:10 b -> a
```

In short: symlinks does **not** have permissions. Anyone can read where the symlink points to. The permissions of the target determines the access.

As Rinzwind points out, the `-h` flag is for [*BSD versions of `chmod`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=chmod&manpath=SuSE+Linux/i386+11.3). It does not work on GNU versions of `chmod`.