# Can't write to a file with open-world write access

Tags: bash, permissions, symbolic-link

I found the `/etc/alternatives/awk` file, and when I got a long list of it's details I got:

```
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/awk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jan 22  2017 /etc/alternatives/awk -> /usr/bin/gawk*
```

So it's a link and has write access to `others`, so I tried this:

```
$ echo hi > /etc/alternatives/awk
bash: /etc/alternatives/awk: Permission denied
```

And then:

```
$ cp /bin/ls /etc/alternatives/awk
cp: unwritable '/etc/alternatives/awk' (mode 0755, rwxr-xr-x); try anyway? y
cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/alternatives/awk': Permission denied
```

How is that possible?

<sub>I know I'm a **normal user**, but I have write access to this file!</sub>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the permissions for the symbolic link?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1151269/is-it-possible-to-change-the-permissions-for-the-symbolic-link)

Comment: @vidarlo my question was not about "how to change a symbolic link permission", it was about "i can't change a file permission", then I understood because it is a sym-link and it points to another file owned by root.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you don't have permissions to write to the file. It's the symbolic link which has `rwx`-permissions for everyone, but you don't write to the link, you write to the file the link points to.

```
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/awk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Apr 28  2018 /etc/alternatives/awk -> /usr/bin/gawk
```

You can see the link points to `/usr/bin/gawk`, so look at it's permissions:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/gawk
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 658072 Feb 11  2018 /usr/bin/gawk
```

`/user/bin/gawk` is owned by *root* and only *root* has write permissions,
that's why you get `Permission denied`.

Comment: Yes. Symlinks always have 777 but that's not considered anyways when accessing the underlying file. Only the permissions and ownership of the _target_ matter.

Comment: Also try `ls -l -L /etc/alternatives/awk` to directly see the information of the target (size, ownership, ...) instead of of the symlink.